# Does linode give you a URL?

Tags: linode

I just got a linode. Under Remote Access I see,

```
li280-180.members.linode.com
```

If I configure my linode properly, can I give this URL to someone to access my hosted files? Say a django application or some archives?

Could I simple set up my server and use this address without registering a domain name?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I don't want to wait for DNS resolving"?

Comment: Could I simple set up my server and use this address without registering a domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Linode [has its own DNS servers](https://www.linode.com/faq.cfm#do-you-host-dns) and [assigns subdomains to each server](https://www.linode.com/faq.cfm#do-i-need-a-domain-name-for-my-linode). Your subdomain `li280-180.members.linode.com` will resolve to your server's IP address.

I can say it works for me: http://li650-40.members.linode.com/ and http://www.fierydragonlord.com/ both resolve to `23.92.20.40`.

Answer (score 2):

I see your apache's default "It works" page when I hit that URL with my browser (assuming that's your linode box).

If you desperately need to shunt some files out of it quickly, use that address as your vhost's 'ServerName', point it at a filesystem path, and let Apache serve an index of that location to your other person.

So, for instance, you could make a directory in /srv/www/temporary_just_for_now/{files_go_here}, and then make an Apache virtualhost which serves from /srv/www/temporary_just_for_now as its DocumentRoot, with Indexes on and with the ServerName set to li280-180.members.linode.com with the name based virtualhost option.